# Accessing input field value without ngModel in Angular2/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Typescript with Angular2, just like in the Angular2 Tour of Heroes tutorial.

I have an input field that I want to attach a `change` event to, so that some custom logic can perform when the field is changed. I need to know the field's current value to perform the logic, so I don't want to bind that field with `ngModel`, as that will override the property before I'm able to retrieve its former value before it was changed.

So I have something like:

```
<input (change)="handleChange(myObj, $event)" value={{ myObj.myField }}... />
```

Then in handleChange:

```
handleChange (obj: MyObjectClass, e: Event) {
  oldValue: number = obj.myField;
  newValue : number = parseInt(e.target.value);

  // Do some logic

  obj.myField = newValue;
}
```

While this works fine in code, the Typescript compiler is throwing an error `error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.` on the line `newValue : number = parseInt(e.target.value);`

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the definition of `EventTarget`, it is like below,

```
 interface EventTarget {
   addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
   dispatchEvent(evt: Event): boolean;
   removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
 }
```

it does not contain the `value` property. so if you want to do it in right way you can use ,

```
 e.target['value']
```

Now the reason why there is no value proerty on EventTarget can to support different type of events , for e.g you may use same Event for `input type checked` and in that case you would like to see `checked` property.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176930/23118) for a HTMLInputEvent type.

Answer (score 3):

To do validation on input values, you are better off writing a custom validator instead of trying to use change event. That being said, you can pass the input value by using a reference to the input like this:

```
<input #myInput (change)="handleChange(myInput.value, $event)" value={{ myObj.myField }}... />
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular2 events don't have direct access to the event's target. You really shouldn't be accessing your value via the raw element, you should always be using a binding.

**whatever.component.ts**

```
export class WhateverComponent {
    private tempField: any;

    private handleChange(obj: MyObjectClass, e: Event) {
        obj.field = this.tempField;
    }
}
```

**whatever.component.html**

```
<input (change)="handleChange(myObj, $event)" [value]="tempField" />
```

If you really must access the element, there is the [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) class. However, this is a major security risk and you should heed the warning in the documentation:

> Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of ElementRef in your code. For more detail, see the [Security Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the official [Get user input from a template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable). so it only happens in your `Template` scope without affecting the `Component` at all.
Something like:

```
<input (change)="handleChange(myObj, newValue.value)" #newValue />

// Method keep the same
handleChange (obj: MyObjectClass, e: Event) {
  oldValue: number = obj.myField;
  newValue : number = parseInt(e.target.value);

  // Do some logic

  obj.myField = newValue;
}
```

A **bonus** is if you need to bind `Enter` key to the `input` field, you do not have to write the annoying `if($event.keyCode == 13) ...`, instead use the [`Key event filtering`](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter) feather and do:

```
(keyup.enter)="onEnter(newvalue.value)"
```